# How to generate the API of my Site using vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to generate the API of my Site ... www.volvobusesindia.com so that i can provide my site API to agents so that cthey can vbook tickets using our API ?

i want the bus booking search box appear in the site will be displayed in others website ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have to have the 'API' first, and then you build your website as a front-end to the API.

An API is just a set of public methods.  That's all.   For a desktop application, these methods will be in a dll.   For a web application these methods will be Web Service, or HTTP Get or HTTP Post methods.  API is just a nice name for this.

You then document all the calls available.   You use the document to build your website, and you give the documents to others so they can build their website.

The API is the foundation of the system.

Comment: I doesn't have any idea of API .... but some of my agents told us to provide us your API

Comment: How to get API ? i want my bus booking search box will displayed in others website

Comment: API is nothing but your webservice methods. Agents can add a search box and call your webservices when a user performs a search

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to either create WCF SOAP based webservices or WCF REST based services.
2. You then need to publish these on a web server so it can be accessed by the agents.
3. You need to document all the API methods and parameters so it is easy for the agents to  use your services.
4. You also need to have an authentication/authorization system in place to ensure your services are used only by the authorized agents.

Comment: How to create create WCF SOAP based webservices or WCF REST based services. can i create it using Visual; Studio 2008 ?

Comment: Yes, you can create WCF SOAP services in VS 2008. If you have no idea about WCF you can start reading some tutorials online like this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx